# What is the best way transfer files from PC/Mac to Network over internet?

Tags: java, windows, macos, browser, upload

My company needs a program that transfer files PC/Mac to Network over internet browsers (such as Chrome, Safari or IE). We decided to write this application in JavaFX so we can use it every platform. The files length are so big (some of them nearly 5-7 GB) so we can't use HTTP.

Is this the right way to do it or do you want to offer something different?

Comment: Why do you need to use web browsers? What about FTP or network shares (yes, MacOS can work with windows SMB shares)?